# ProgressBar is not updating while downloading a file in Android

Tags: android, download, progress-bar, progressdialog

I've read almost every similar topic but I couldn't find a solution. So I decided to ask my own.

I want to download a file and show a progress dialog during the operation. The file gets downloaded successfully.

The first problem is that the progress bar doesn't update during the download operation. It just stays %0 and when the download is finished, the dialog disappears as expected.

The second problem is - I noticed this by accident - when my activity gets updated (for example, when screen orientation is changed) the dialog disappears but the download continues.

I hope someone can help.

Here's my code:

```
package com.mehmetakiftutuncu.downloadunzipshow;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    final String LOG_TAG = "DownloadUnzipShow";

    final String RELATIVE_PATH = "mehmetakiftutuncu";
    final String FILE_NAME = "...";
    final String FILE_URL = "...";
    final String FULL_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + RELATIVE_PATH + "/";;

    Button buttonDownload, buttonUnzip, buttonShow;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public class MyFileDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        boolean isSuccessful = true;

        InputStream inputStream;
        OutputStream outputStream;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            prepareProgressDialog();

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Downloading: " + FILE_URL + " to " + FULL_PATH + FILE_NAME);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            int count;

            try
            {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

                connection.connect();

                int lengthOfFile = connection.getContentLength();

                File path = new File(FULL_PATH);
                if(!path.exists())
                {
                    path.mkdir();
                }

                inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(FULL_PATH + FILE_NAME);

                byte[] data = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;
                int percentage = 0;

                while((count = inputStream.read(data)) != -1)
                {
                    total += count;

                    percentage = (int) ((total / lengthOfFile) * 100);

                    publishProgress(String.valueOf(percentage));

                    outputStream.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                isSuccessful = false;
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "An error occured while downloading. Details: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values)
        {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            progressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(isSuccessful)
            {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "File is successfully downloaded to: " + FULL_PATH + FILE_NAME);
            }

            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonDownload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_download);

        buttonDownload.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void prepareProgressDialog()
    {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.dialog_title));
        progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.dialog_message) + FILE_URL);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setMax(100);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.button_download:
                new MyFileDownloader().execute(FILE_URL);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why convert an Integer to String back to Integer?

Comment: It was Integer before (AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>) but I tried many things. I think it was one of the silly things I tried. I don't think that's the problem here, or is it? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The first problem is that the progress bar doesn't update during the
>   download operation. It just stays %0 and when the download is
>   finished, the dialog disappears as expected.

That is happening because the line:

```
percentage = (int) ((total / lengthOfFile) * 100);
```

always return `0` as you're doing an integer java division where `total` is smaller than `lengthOfFile`. Make `total` a `double` value. Also don't cast the percentage as a `String`, modify the second generic argument of the `AsyncTask` to be an `Integer`.

> The second problem is - I noticed this by accident - when my activity
>   gets updated (for example, when screen orientation is changed) the
>   dialog disappears but the download continues.

On a configuration change(a rotation for example) the `Activity` will be recreated killing your dialog in the process. If you want to re-show the dialog you'll need to keep the `AsyncTask` across the configuration change by passing it to the `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` method of the `Activity`(or you could use fragments). In the `onCreate` method use `getLastNonConfigurationInstance` to see if you have a task retained and still running and reshow the dialog. Also you really shouldn't make the `AsyncTask` a inner class in the `Activity` because you'll tie it to the activity.

Comment: Changing total variable to of type double solved the first problem but it seems onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() method is deprecated. I'm going to try this solution now for the second problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14528795/1367813

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @mAt Yes it's deprecated, I recommended it because I don't know if you had contact with the `Fragment` API. You could do it like in the answer below but you could get in trouble if you're not careful.

Comment: Frankly I don't know much about Fragments yet. I also couldn't solve my problem doing what is suggested in the the answer below. Could you explain a little more how can I use the methods you suggested (either Fragments or these b-methods above)?

Comment: @mAt I've looked through some code that I had. Check this out https://gist.github.com/4637742

Comment: The code you gave solved my problem. I accepted the answer. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: @mAt When you become more experienced(not too advanced) with Android have a look at fragments.

Answer (score 0):

THe dialog disappearing-  are you capturing orientation config changes, or are you letting Android do it?  If you're letting Android do it, it will kill your activity and recreate it, which will destroy your dialog.  The async task wouldn't get killed because the async task is owned by the system.  To fix that, add android:configChange="orientation" to your manifest for the activity.  General rule of thumb is if you want to have dialogs persist through rotation you need to do that.

Comment: Currently Android handles it. I'll try what you suggested for the disappearance of the dialog. Thank you. I still have the progress problem though.

Comment: Put a log or breakpoint in onProgressUpdate and see if its called.  If it isn't, try throwing a dialog.postInvalidate() in there and see if its just that you aren't redrawing it for some reason.

Comment: I got the progress bar working as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/a/14529136/1367813 However, even after adding android:configChange="orientation" my dialog still disappears.

Comment: My mistake, its configChanges  with an s